# Android SDK update for L give error java(TM) platform Stack Exchange binary has stopped working

Tags: android

I try to update Android-SDK for Android L from Android SDK Manager.while update I get get error message message java(TM)  platform Stack Exchange binary has stopped working, And now my eclipse is not working.

Comment: which java version are you using?

Comment: i am using java version "1.6.0_13"

Comment: have you tried downloading java 7?